# Calling static library written C from iPhone/Objective-C project

Tags: iphone, multithreading, static

I want to reference my static library written in C from Objective-C/iPhone project,but I was wondering if it is possible to reference a threaded function from the Objective-C module?

My concern is, since thread function is not part of the standard C library there might be unresolved linking during the compilation process.

Any thoughts/advice would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Threading has absolutely nothing to do with linking. Threading is the act of running several code branches at the same time (virtually; if there are several CPUs and/or several CPU cores then virtually becomes literally). Linking is the act of finding functions in a library so your code can call them. There's no relationship between the two with the sole exception of linking a library that provides threading support (which you don't need to care about, as Xcode already does that you).

There are several blog entries that explain how to link a static library into your project.

If you're concerned that the library is not thread safe you need to make sure to use a `NSLock` around every call to functions from that library. See for example [this article](http://alienryderflex.com/NSLock.html) on what `NSLock` is and why you'll need it.